# Destination not hotter than 25 degrees celsius

Tags: health, weather-and-climate, work

I search for a destination where the weather **in summer is not hotter than 25 degrees celsius** (let it be 29 at maximum). Being exposed to a hot environment causes problems for my immune system. As I have the ability to work remotely, I would consider travelling for about half a year while working and then returning to where I actually live (central europe).

My native language is German (German citizen) and my English as well as my Russian skills are quite good. The only requirements in this case would be:

- internet connection
- no city prohibiting foreigners to enter (Norilsk in Russia for example)
- number of inhabitants should be more than 50 000

Comment: Sorry but we don't give advice on where to travel to. Also, note that remote working can cause visa problems.

Comment: @Tor-Einar Jarnbjo "I have no idea what an 'average maximum' in Copenhagen is, the numbers can either be average or maximum, but not both" The average maximum monthly temperature is the answer to the question "In an average year, how hot is the hottest day in this month?" For example, take the average temperature of the hottest day in each of the last 50 Julys.

Comment: @DavidRicherby If that is correct, the number does not say much at all about how warm it actually is.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Given the numbers in the link in Zach's (now deleted) answer, I think it must be the average over all summer days of "maximum temperature during that day".

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think you're right -- I've only seen it done monthly (e.g., in Wikipedia's climate charts) but Zach described it as "in summer".

Comment: Comparing the data in the chart Zach linked to and 'proper' historical weather data, the numbers in the chart are a close match to average and mininum temperatures and not max and min as the chart key implies. For example, the min, avg and max temperatures in Copenhagen in July 2018 were 11°C, 21°C and 33°C. Here, the average temperature also includes measurements during the night, so it does not say much about how warm it actually gets during the day.

Comment: Do you actually mean "in summer (local season)," or do you mean "when it is summer in my home country"? If the latter, then you could consider switching hemispheres every six months.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: On the other hand, the summer of 2018 was much hotter than usual in Copenhagen.

Comment: @HenningMakholm How much is 'much hotter'? July 2017 was unusually cold, but in the previous five years (2012-2016), the temperatures in Copenhagen exceeded 30°C each year. Also this year, the temperature in Copenhagen has already reached 32.2°C. And why is this relevant for the question, if OP wants to stay where the temperatures don't exceed 25°C? It is not at all unusual that the temperature in Copenhagen rises well above that.

Comment: @Tor, I don't think this is particularly relevant to answering the OP's question,  no. Just contributing to the idle speculation about what exactly it was Zach's graph showed. We usually have a handful of days that reach 30ish degrees, but 2018 had unusually *many* of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The west coast of Ireland will suit your requirements as long as you select a town or village that has what you need. 
There can be a heat wave but even then the temperatures are relatively low, 20's mostly.
The father north, the fewer tourist and a bit inland you will find even less tourist while the weather is still cool.

As Ireland and Germany are both EU, you should not have problems with working there. You may have to register.

The west coast of Jutland, Denmark will likely also be within your temperature limits as are parts of the west coast of Norway and both those are EU or EEA and not to hard to arrange long term relocation and remote work permits.

Comment: I also nominate Iceland. You'd be lucky to see 20 degree weather there.

Comment: Are there Irish villages that meet the need of "number of inhabitants should be more than 50 000"?

Comment: There are villages over 50, not over 50000, but there are Irish towns/cities where they likely reach that number. (I had overlooked that when I answered the question.)

Comment: Galway and Limerick are on the west coast, and have populations over 50k.